# How to get closest value to number from adding array elements

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

lets suppose i have number 20 and set of numbers n "n here is 4 just for example" {7, 2, 9, 3}

i want to know the closest value greater than number 20 and the closest value smaller than 20 that i can get from single element or adding multiple elements from the array together.

**i'm not sure what data structure or algorithm i should use**

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's known as a knapsack problem (well, your problem is a slight variation, but it doesn't really matter).

You can use dynamic programming if the sum of numbers is reasonably low (the state is the sum, the value is true or false depending on whether this sum is reachable). The time complexity of this approach is `O(N * SUM)`.

If the number elements of the array is small, you can also iterate over all subsets and compute the sum for each of them (it would require `O(2^N * Poly(N))` time).

If the number of elements is small, but not so small, you can use the meet-in-middle technique to make the previous solution slightly better (`O(2^(N/2) * Poly(N)`).